# How to fetch maven dependencies for quarkus:dev with dependency:go-offline

Tags: docker, maven, quarkus, skaffold

I have a set up where a quarkus microservice docker image is based on the docker image of the *mavencache*. *Mavencache* image is created by

```
RUN maven dependency:go-offline
```

and it fetches a certain amount of the dependencies from the pom.xml. I'd rather say almost all dependencies.

But when the quarkus microservice docker container is being created, it runs:

```
CMD ["mvn", "quarkus:dev"]
```

and this command fetches some "Additional dependencies" which takes additional time which I would like to save. That's actually why I've created *mavencache* base docker image.

[image: Component diagram]

Does anyone from the quarkus can help with understanding why `mvn quarkus:dev fetches` additional maven dependencies instead of fetching them during `mvn dependency:go-offline`?

**UPD1**

The following picture describes how I expect the whole caching schema to be working. Despite of the `mvn package` or `mvn quarkus:dev` it should NOT fetch any additional dependencies on when some file in the `src/` directory.
[image: This is how I expect the whole caching schema should work]

Comment: I assume you mean `mvn dependency:go-offline` in your RUN command. Could it be that quarkus have an additional dependency mechanism to resolve something, so that it is not just what is specified by mvn plugin and mvn dependency? Just guessing, not an answer :)

Comment: Why do you do `mvn quarkus:dev` in the container? Shouldn't you rather run a jar or a native executable in the container?

If that's not a mistake:
are the `quarkus-something-deployment` artifacts that you see downloaded? 
Your Quarkus app has only runtime dependencies listed in the pom file. When building it, quarkus-maven-plugin also uses build-time dependencies (with `-deployment` suffix).

Can you replace `dependency:go-offline` with `package`? It should resolve all the dependencies

Comment: @Michał Szynkiewicz, yes, there are a lot of the artifacts 'quarkus-*-deployment'